# Run a macro multiple times down the sheet

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have a table that takes user input data and fills in the rest of the table from the data. So far I have created a macro that automatically fills in the table from the users data.

I want to have the user input the amount of times they want to run the macro (as each table displays a days worth of input) but every time the macro runs it just fills in the same space and doesn't display multiple days worth of tables.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your macro, let's assume you have a generic macro that stores user input in a column:

```
Sub InputMacro()
    Range("B1:B100").Value = InputBox("What do you want to store in column B")
End Sub
```

If you want to loop over this, you first need to parameterize the macro, i.e. make the part flexible that you want to change it in each loop step. E.g. if you want to run over multiple columns, you could do this:

```
Sub InputMacro_new(intColNumber As Integer, Optional lngRowNumber As Long = 100)
    Cells(1, intColNumber).Resize(lngRowNumber) = _
        InputBox("What do you want to store in column " & _
        Split(Cells(1, intColNumber).Address, "$")(1))
End Sub
```

This will now accept a parameter `intColNumber`, i.e. you can call `InputMacro_New 2` to fill column B. Note that I also provided an *optional parameter* `lngRowNumber`that by default is 100. You do not need to provided this parameter - but if you want you can override the default, e.g. `InputMacro_New 2, 50`)

Now you can create a loop in another macro that calls your macro:

```
Sub MyLoop()
    Dim intCol As Integer, varMaxCols As Variant
    varMaxCols = InputBox("How many columns do you want to fill?")

    If Not IsNumber(varMaxCols) Then Exit Sub
    ElseIf varMaxCols < 1 Or varMaxCols > 255 Then Exit Sub

    For intCol = 1 To varMaxCols
        InputMacro_new intCol
    Next intCol

End Sub
```

Of course, if you want you can also combine both into one larger macro - but esp. for larger macros it is best practice to split it into smaller procedures.